# Project Euler problem 5 Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve [problem 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) of Project Euler which is:

2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder. What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

My program complies but when I execute it it displays the following message:

Segmentation fault: 11

```
void integerDivision(int num)
{
    int i = 0;
    int smallestNumber = 0;
    int remainder = 0;
    int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                    11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

    for(int j = i; j < 20; j++)
    {
        remainder = num % numbers[j];
        if (remainder  == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
            integerDivision(num + 1);
        }  
    }
    smallestNumber = num / numbers[i];
    cout << smallestNumber << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    integerDivision(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `num` is negative, this goes wrong in many ways.

Comment: Probably a stack overflow due to excessive recursion. Check the exit condition with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try debugging your code by reducing the number of values from 20 to 5.

> ```
> int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
>
> for(int j = i; j < 5; j++)
> ```

A couple of issues with you code:

1. Since you are calling `integerDivision(num + 1)` for all the numbers not dividing  `num`, it will create an exponential growth and your program will timeout. To fix this you can add `return;` after `integerDivision(num + 1)`
2. Your code will now work for smaller values, say 10 but will still fail for 20. You're using recursion which will cause stack overflow for large numbers. Try doing similar thing with iteration instead.

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you said and Stack Overflow Is caused when numbers size is bigger than 12.

Comment: @Ratman305 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.